# difference of "name" and "as" attribute in layout files?

Tags: magento2, layout

the [docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html) read:

> NAME - Name that can be used to address the block to which this
> attribute is assigned. The name must be unique per generated page. If
> not specified, an automatic name will be assigned in the format
> ANONYMOUS_n
>
> AS - An alias name that serves as identifier in the scope of the
> parent element.

They're both unique identifiers. When do I use the name and when the alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `AS` is **never** required.
You should **always** add a `NAME` before adding an `AS`

`AS` is an alias to `NAME` to make it more readable.

It can be used in templates files (.phtml) in `getChild` / `getChildHtml` methods, but it can't be used to reference the block in layouts file.

**For exemple :**

In a first module, you have this layout (simplified):

```
<page>
    <body>
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Parent" name="vendor_module_parent" template="Vendor_Module::parent.phtml">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Child" name="vendor_module_child" as="child" template="Vendor_Module::child.phtml">
        </block>
    </body>
</page>
```

-> In `Vendor_Module::parent.phtml` :
Both `$block->getChildHtml('vendor_module_child')` and `$block->getChildHtml('child')` will work.

-> In another layout :

```
<page>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="vendor_module_child">   <!-- Working -->

        </referenceBlock>
    
        <referenceBlock name="child">   <!-- Not working -->

        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Same for `move` instructions.

Hope this helps.